# Rxjs make sequential calls using concatMap

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I would like to make two sequentially calls (if the first one is completed, call the second one):

My Code is like:

```
        myApiClient
        .firstApiCall()
        .pipe(take(1),
            concatMap (firstResult => {
            doSomethingWithResponse(firstResult);
            return myApiClient.secondApiCall();
        }), take(1))
        .subscribe(secondResult => {
            doSomethingWithResponse(firstResult);
        }, error => {
            catchSecondApiCallError(error);
        });
```

First question: is that the right way to make sequential calls?
Second question: How could I catch the error for the first Call?

Comment: What should happen if the first one fails - would you like to continue with the second in that case?

Comment: @NicholasK no, if the first one fails, the second one shouldn't be called (the behaviour now is correct). I want to just handle the error of the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the right way to chain sequential api calls using rxjs. For the second question you may make use of the [`catchError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) operator.

```
    myApiClient
    .firstApiCall()
    .pipe(
        take(1),
        catchError(e => {
          console.log('Error caught from first api ', e);
          return EMPTY;
        }),
        concatMap (firstResult => {
          doSomethingWithResponse(firstResult);
          return myApiClient.secondApiCall();
    }), take(1))
    .subscribe(secondResult => {
        doSomethingWithResponse(secondResult);
    }, error => {
        catchSecondApiCallError(error);
    });
```

EMPTY is imported from:

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: thank you. Only for the sake of curiosit: Would be there also a way in order to continue with the second call, in case that the first one would fail?

Comment: You can try using [onErrorResumeNext](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/onErrorResumeNext) for that.